# Move layer with CAKeyframeAnimation - layer back to first position

Tags: objective-c, cakeyframeanimation

At first to move my layer from point to point I use that code:

```
        CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
        anim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPt];
        anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPt];
        anim.repeatCount = 0;
        anim.duration = 1.0;
       [self.firstBall.ballLayer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position"];
```

And this to after animation clear first layer and redraw it in other place.

```
    NSInteger firstBallIndex = [self.fieldsArray indexOfObject:self.firstBall];
           NSInteger secondBallIndex = [self.fieldsArray indexOfObject:self.secondBall];
           Field* ballFrom = [self.fieldsArray objectAtIndex:firstBallIndex];
           Field* ballTo = [self.fieldsArray objectAtIndex:secondBallIndex];
           ballTo.ballLayer = ballFrom.ballLayer;
           CGPoint startPt = CGPointMake(self.firstBall.ballCoordinates.x,self.firstBall.ballCoordinates.y);
    CGPoint endPt = CGPointMake(self.secondBall.ballCoordinates.x,self.secondBall.ballCoordinates.y);
    ballTo.ballLayer.frame = CGRectMake(endPt.x, endPt.y, self.ballSize, self.ballSize);
             ballFrom.ballLayer = nil;
             [self.fieldsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:firstBallIndex withObject:ballFrom];
             [self.fieldsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:secondBallIndex withObject:ballTo];
```

But next I try to animate my layer to move few time. So I use that code:

```
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    NSMutableArray * pathArray = [algorithm CreatePath];
  CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, self.firstBall.ballCoordinates.x, self.firstBall.ballCoordinates.y);
        for (NSValue * pointValue in pathArray) {
            CGPoint point = [pointValue CGPointValue];
            Field* field = [self FindFieldWithPoint:point];
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, field.ballCoordinates.x, field.ballCoordinates.y);
        }
 CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.duration = 2.0;
pathAnimation.path = path;
[UIView animateWithDuration:5
                      delay:5
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     [self.firstBall.ballLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"position"];
                 }
                 completion:^ (BOOL finished)
 {
     if (finished) {


         ballTo.ballLayer.frame = CGRectMake(endPt.x, endPt.y, self.ballSize, self.ballSize);
         ballFrom.ballLayer = nil;
         [self.fieldsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:firstBallIndex withObject:ballFrom];
         [self.fieldsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:secondBallIndex withObject:ballTo];
     }
 }];
```

Now:

1. When I comment code in 'finished':
   my layer animate ok, move from point to point, but in the end it back to first coordinates
2. When I uncomment code in 'finished':
   my layer move from first coordinates to last, like it not know places between :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5 // and so on
```

Do not try to combine layer animation with view animation this way. Just add the animation to the layer and stand back. :)

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = 
    [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.duration = 2.0;
pathAnimation.path = path;
[self.firstBall.ballLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"position"];
```

And set your final position *immediately* to prevent the jump-back later:

```
ballTo.ballLayer.frame = 
    CGRectMake(endPt.x, endPt.y, self.ballSize, self.ballSize);
```

If you still need to hear about when the animation ends, then set a delegate on your `pathAnimation`.

Comment: immediately means that set frame before addAnimation ? I have problem with set delegate to path Animation, this not work :/:     [pathAnimation setDelegate:self]; - (void)moveAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
}

Comment: Main problem is why when I uncomment ballTo.ballLayer.frame = CGRectMake(endPt.x, endPt.y, self.ballSize, self.ballSize);
 my layer move directly to last point? I only hope that when I use en animation delegate this problem resolved it self...

Comment: Immediately means immediately. Add the animation to the layer and set the layer final position. Together.

Comment: You have trouble with the delegate because you set the delegate but you used the wrong action method. It is animationDidStop:finished:

Comment: This code sample didn't work for me on iOS 8. I fixed it by adding  CATransaction.setDisableActions(true). It is also described in book provided by @matt